# Loading Rubywork Facets unto a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, module, require, helper

I want to use a particular rubyworks facets unto a helper:

```
require 'core/facets/string/snakecase'

module GenericTableHelper

  def generic_table_theadlink(head_title, order_parameter = head_title.snake_case  )
    render(:partial => 'common_partials/generic_table/theadlink', :locals => {:head_title => head_title,
                                                                              :order_parameter => order_parameter})
  end

end
```

I get the error:

```
No such file to load -- core/facets/string/snakecase
```

Checked gemfile:

```
gem 'facets'
```

How do I load Rubyworks Facets unto the Helper? and any other model/view/controller

Answer (score 0):

I think the `core` is leading you astray.

```
require 'facets/string/snakecase`
```